# Laravel - blade append section

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, laravel-blade

i need to run a js script in a subview, so i have a section with all my scripts and in the subview i try to append my script to the existing scripts.

HTML PAGE:

```
<html><head></head><body></body>@yield('scripts')</html>
```

SECTION:

```
@section('scripts') <!-- my standard scripts --> @stop
```

SUBVIEW:

```
@section('scripts') <!-- my new script --> @append
```

i already try with @parent inside subview @section('scripts') but doesn't work.

thank's

Answer (score 1):

You main view must have the scripts like this

```
@section('scripts')
    // your scripts here
@show
```

Then you can use the `@parent` tag to add scripts to the `section` from the child template

```
@section('scripts')
@parent
    // your other scripts
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

just read on blade templates laravel link bellow

[I've read on this link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
</head>
<body>
    @section('sidebar')
        This is the master sidebar.
    @show

    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

example code for the parent part

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('sidebar')
@parent

<p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

for the child view use the code above